# Cannot pass values from one def to another, says too many values to unpack

Tags: python, function, return

I honestly do not know what to do. The questions I got on StackOverflow were about strings and csv inputs, but these variables I am expecting are different. Help would be very much appreciated.  I always get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`. I want the code to pass the three returned variables from speedCalc() to something I could use in the calculations in spellCheck() (line 35). What should I do?

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import random
import string
import sys
import string
import sys

#from getkey import getkey

def generateTest():
    mylines = []                              
    with open ('phrases.txt', 'rt') as myfile:  # Open phrases.txt for reading the typing tests
        for line in myfile:                   # For each line of text,
            mylines.append(line)              # add that line to the list.

    # Converting lines of list to select a random phrase
    listLen = len(mylines) - 1 
    return (mylines[random.randint(0,listLen)])

def speedCalc():
    # words / time passed (assuming it is 5)
    start = time.time()
    test = input(print(generateTest()))
    end = time.time()
    timePassed = (end - start) 
    generateTestLen = len(generateTest())

    return test
    return timePassed
    return ((generateTestLen/5)/timePassed)*60

def spellCheck():
    test, timePassed, wpm = speedCalc()
    diff = 0
    correctChars = 0

    file_A = generateTest()
    file_B = test

    read_A=open(file_A,'r').read()
    read_B=open(file_B,'r').read()

    for char_a, char_b in zip(read_A, read_B):
        if char_a == char_b:
            correctChars = correctChars+1
    read_A_len = len(read_A)

    correctPercent = (correctChars/read_A_len)*100

    errors = read_A_len - correctChars
    errorRate = errors/timePassed

    netWPM = wpm - errorRate

    return correctPercent
    return netWPM

correctPercent, netWPM = spellCheck()
print(netWPM)
```

Comment: whoa whoa whoa, only one `return` statement per function, please. make it a three-tuple: `return test, timePassed, ...[the other thing here]`.

Comment: [Code samples](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be *minimal*, complete and representative.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to return multiple values from a function?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38508/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
return test
return timePassed
return ((generateTestLen/5)/timePassed)*60
```

use

```
return test, timePassed, ((generateTestLen/5)/timePassed)*60
```

Your function as you defined in your example just returnes test and exits then. The second and third return is not executed any more.

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

When a `return` statement is reached, a function stops. Any code after the return statement is never executed.

The code

```
return test
return timePassed
return ((generateTestLen/5)/timePassed)*60
```

is equivalent to

```
return test
```

You should return a tuple of three values. Use

```
return test, timePassed, ((generateTestLen/5)/timePassed)*60
```

Adjust `spellCheck` accordingly, it has the same problem.

Comment: Thank you too! I am just getting started with tuples and it's kind of confusing since I couldn't find any good text tutorials on it.